# How to enter prompts in bash script for python manage.py

Tags: python, django, shell

Hi I want to use python manage.py changepassword  command with bash script.

When I do it askes double time for new password. How can I answer those in bash ?

```
python manage.py changepassword testuser
Changing password for user 'testuser'
Password:
Password (again):
Password changed successfully for user 'testuser'
```

I know I can do  it like below but how can i do that without using below and Expect. Since environment I am using does not have Expect.

```
echo "from accounts.models import User;u= User.objects.get(username='testuser'); u.set_password('$1'); u.save();" | python3 manage.py shell;
```

Edit: manage.py commands also is a option but my question could it be done with bash ?

Comment: what do you mean by Expect ?

Comment: Create a custom management command that takes the necessary parameters. Ideally, it may look like `python manage.py custom_change_password_cmd testuser new-password`

Comment: Erondem refer this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html

Comment: @c.grey please refer here https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/#:~:text=Expect%20command%20or%20expect%20scripting%20language%20is%20a%20language%20that,response%20without%20any%20user%20interaction.

Comment: Thanks but manage.py commands is not a option I can use right now because of the deployment environment. could it be done via bash script?

Comment: @erondem : I guess you were thinking of Expect so that it automatically supplies the password twice instead of fixing the root cause, right? If you don't want to install Tcl/Expect, you could install [Shell-Expect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) instead. Using plain bash would work only if the password is being read from stdin.